# SQL get same values with different id

Tags: sql, sqlite

Imagine I have the following tables in SQLite:

**colors**:

```
id INTEGER primary key
name TEXT
brightnes INTEGER
```

**painting**:

```
id INTEGER primary key
name TEXT
colors TEXT
material TEXT
```

**paint**:

```
color_id foreign key
painting_id foreign key
```

Now I would like to select all the paintings where the color red and green was used. How could I do this? I thought about something like:

```
SELECT name
FROM painting 
WHERE colors.name = 'Green' 
  AND colors.name = 'Red' 
  AND colors.id = paint.color_id 
  AND paint.painting_id = painting.id;
```

Unfortunately, this is not returning what I would like to get. I read a lot about `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but can't set my mind around this.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use GROUP BY and HAVING! Hint: COUNT(DISTINCT colors.name).

Comment: What does painting.colors contain?

Answer (score 0):

How is the connection made between the two tables?

You should have primary and foreign key if you have two separate tables.

Than you should use inner join to join the tables and get the results you want.

Also you should use "where" clause

Example:

```html
select * 
from painting 
inner join colors on colorsFkey = colorsId 
where colors.name = 'red' OR/AND colors.name = 'green'
```

Try also learning and and or and also table connection with primary and foreign key

Comment: the problem is I want the painting where both colors are present. Or works but if I use and nothing comes out anymore even though there must be solutions

Comment: Why do you guess *this is mysql*? The tag of the question is SQLite.

Comment: You should also distinct primary keys from foreign keys adding some keywords like fk and pk so we can know how to distinct them here..

Comment: Hmm do you have the two colors into the data of one painting so you can perform a search like that..

Comment: Can you give me the data you have inside the tables..

Comment: As seen from your post now you just have foreign key on the third table paint and perform the sql query on the painting table.. why do you need a third table so you can generate a painting with colors? You should combine painting and colors tables with foreign and primary key in order to generate a painting.. also you are using way too much and clauses.. again i would ask you for the data inside the tables.. to see what you have